# What is the best practice to receive a single type from an union type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this kind of code

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
}

type MyType = string | MyInterface;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.getValueAsString('Hello World'));
    console.log(this.getValueAsString({name: 'Hello World'}));
  }

  // I want to return 'Hello World' for both possible types
  getValueAsString(myValue: MyType): string {
    // not working because compiler says name is no property of string
    // return myValue.name ? myValue.name : myValue;
  }
}
```

The problem is, that in each way I tried the compiler is always showing up because something does not fit for either of the types.

What would be the best solution for `getValueAsString`?

(stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrty3q)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640886/how-to-check-if-property-exists-if-obj-is-one-of-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) for that:

```
getValueAsString(myValue: MyType): string {
  return typeof myValue === "string" ? myValue : myValue.name;
}
```

In the above, since the TypeScript compiler knows that `myValue` will be either `string` or `MyInterface`, the `typeof myValue === "string"` guard tells it that in the true part of the conditional (after the `?`), `myValue` is a string, and in the false part (after the `:`), it's `MyInterface`.